# Folium Heatmap Unexpected Weighted Results

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I am attempting to use Folium to display a map of After Renovation Values for houses in a certain area. The higher the ARV, the "hotter" I want that area of the map.

I am trying to take advantage of Folium's weighted heatmap, however, random points seem to be way hotter than others despite having a lower ARV (and thus lower weighted value). When I use a lot of points for my heatmap (>1000) only one point is "hot" and the rest are cold. See image.

I am normalizing the ARV values between 0.5 and 1.5. I have tried other normalized values with no success.

In the screenshot, note that there are many points on this map with a higher ARV value and heatmap weighted value. Also there are other areas of the map with more points clustered together. So I have no idea why this one is the only one that is hot.

Below is some sample data.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from folium import Map
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
import csv_helper


# Custom function that converts a CSV with Address, Latitude, Longitude, ARV to python List
csv_list = csv_helper.csv_to_list('arvs.csv')

# Normalized min & max
new_min = 0.5
new_max = 1.5

hmap = Map(location=[41.496551, -81.65133], zoom_start=100)

# Add markers to map
for address in csv_list:
    arv = int(address['ARV'])
    # newvalue= (max'-min')/(max-min)*(value-min)+min'.
    arv_normalized = round(float((new_max-new_min)/(500000-40000)*(arv-40000)+new_min),3)
    
    # Show ARV value and normalized value (for heatmap) for debugging purposes
    tooltip = "$" + address['ARV']
    tooltip += " " + str(arv_normalized)
    folium.Circle(
        [address['Latitude'], address['Longitude']], popup="<i></i>", tooltip=tooltip, radius=150
    ).add_to(hmap)

# -------------------------------------------------

# Create heatmap with normalized ARV values
final_list = []
for address in csv_list:
    arv = int(address['ARV'])
    # newvalue= (max'-min')/(max-min)*(value-min)+min'.
    arv_normalized = round(float((new_max-new_min)/(500000-40000)*(arv-40000)+new_min),3)
    final_list.append((float(address['Latitude']), float(address['Longitude']), arv_normalized))
# ---------------------------------------


final_map = HeatMap(
    final_list,
    min_opacity=0.2,
    radius=40, 
    blur=40, 
)

hmap.add_child(final_map)

hmap.save('index.html')
```

[image: Heatmap picture]

```
ARV,Latitude,Longitude
80000,35.20271,-90.008334
120000,41.391633,-81.522691
130000,41.509003,-81.553549
250000,35.058779,-89.881985
160000,41.439312,-81.922154
410000,41.521241,-81.405547
350000,41.388637,-81.414451
360000,41.473301,-81.519901
264000,35.014625,-89.81703
175000,41.513541,-81.536019
410000,41.521241,-81.405547
180000,34.996242,-89.838076
110000,41.496551,-81.65133
110000,41.496551,-81.65133
140000,41.453832,-81.792491
230000,35.058779,-89.881985
150000,41.481158,-81.747563
360000,41.476918,-81.855462
130000,41.526998,-81.504134
350000,41.488054,-81.929447
850000,35.124245,-89.894052
260000,41.496551,-81.65133
400000,41.557968,-81.451966
240000,41.425264,-81.953059
110000,40.788578,-81.416775
140000,41.498209,-81.5627
120000,41.411274,-81.584893
250000,41.378911,-81.754235
250000,41.489806,-81.51235
100000,41.395767,-81.535133
40000,40.783719,-81.379159
130000,41.395311,-81.704656
140000,41.513541,-81.536019
65000,41.449614,-81.596527
160000,35.112125,-89.954644
70000,41.724602,-81.250865
120000,41.496551,-81.65133
120000,41.536174,-81.536244
75000,41.467058,-82.163095
155000,41.395311,-81.704656
500000,41.522976,-81.409499
250000,41.510947,-81.48978
165000,41.463768,-81.555838
230000,41.399833,-81.948991
270000,41.399833,-81.948991
100000,41.56134,-81.536752
260000,41.476192,-81.787702
270000,41.509563,-81.597207
145000,41.409494,-81.732268
250000,41.481919,-81.891249
130000,41.610679,-81.494706
360000,35.119919,-89.986065
370000,41.485596,-81.968291
240000,41.459678,-81.562217
480000,41.566412,-81.460469
135000,41.412794,-81.550415
390000,41.33429,-81.650159
390000,41.33429,-81.650159
90000,41.40014,-81.591994
110000,41.403025,-81.510372
250000,41.496551,-81.65133
165000,41.417272,-81.708537
230000,35.038678,-89.826112
170000,41.360592,-81.784523
230000,41.396157,-81.791135
420000,41.429342,-81.410058
310000,41.331445,-81.788
160000,41.314045,-81.831505
330000,41.347437,-81.715494
120000,41.434043,-81.713272
130000,41.389556,-81.742872
400000,41.313209,-81.827588
180000,35.029085,-89.830267
80000,41.395767,-81.535133
310000,41.313209,-81.827588
40000,35.179305,-89.987687
60000,41.460838,-81.721954
220000,35.009043,-89.803944
65000,41.517454,-81.659181
200000,41.402621,-81.666393
350000,41.475409,-81.831745
300000,41.432224,-81.941826
170000,41.405186,-81.71861
90000,41.478149,-81.649167
120000,41.442856,-81.774558
145000,41.444031,-81.813938
155000,41.424741,-81.641074
35000,41.44021,-81.640585
180000,35.048025,-89.874334
190000,41.397042,-81.792927
50000,41.569235,-81.553251
180000,41.50035,-81.569165
55000,41.518024,-81.625218
55000,41.490536,-81.76919
95000,39.821712,-86.081666
370000,41.481909,-81.936075
70000,41.607244,-81.503932
95000,39.821863,-86.081666
95000,41.44741,-81.550367
320000,41.473999,-81.847547
70000,35.152693,-89.959701
155000,41.457457,-81.552897
280000,41.48613,-81.53254
80000,35.059993,-90.089206
300000,41.432411,-81.476042
200000,41.481345,-81.713879
120000,41.496551,-81.65133
500000,41.454979,-81.933205
150000,41.496551,-81.65133
130000,41.595095,-81.532663
100000,41.433458,-81.69937
80000,35.112125,-89.954644
90000,41.431867,-81.776982
140000,41.437502,-81.719623
140000,41.437502,-81.719623
50000,41.40909,-81.727864
120000,41.446436,-81.54706
255000,41.474547,-81.520539
114000,41.447594,-81.786672
146000,41.396294,-81.719042
205000,41.496551,-81.65133
61000,41.460998,-81.664012
161000,41.526099,-81.480258
139000,41.616156,-81.516354
72000,35.261568,-90.03766
262000,41.388719,-81.655214
236000,41.42287,-81.880106
140000,41.496551,-81.65133
250000,41.481431,-81.816511
112000,41.393322,-81.568783
58000,41.474515,-81.615786
152000,35.160754,-89.941566
57000,41.45761,-81.711104
286000,41.526976,-81.625285
254000,41.502558,-81.591683
144000,41.565275,-81.522166
168672,41.496551,-81.65133
158000,41.515294,-81.480691
199000,35.145123,-89.923967
142000,41.407764,-81.705747
380000,41.515489,-81.498872
264000,41.459379,-81.546031
130000,41.59737,-81.519512
263000,41.470533,-81.856104
109000,41.616926,-81.489452
142000,41.496551,-81.65133
172000,41.468386,-81.797626
45000,41.445988,-81.637576
381000,41.479981,-81.796735
86000,41.451478,-81.570577
316000,35.141949,-89.89007
171000,41.340916,-81.67061
186000,41.527123,-81.488265
118000,41.390367,-81.857135
272000,41.493983,-81.580516
192000,41.474904,-81.790612
716000,41.497215,-81.577634
74000,41.455386,-81.644509
217000,41.474904,-81.790612
249000,41.54746,-81.464124
76000,41.401175,-81.591213
161000,35.01404,-89.842125
148000,41.458904,-81.718525
296000,41.474576,-81.510153
51000,41.496551,-81.65133
86000,41.534577,-81.563225
274000,41.331352,-82.079267
87000,41.408078,-81.550402
111000,41.495959,-81.646259
236000,41.473035,-81.924042
236000,41.473035,-81.924042
87000,41.408078,-81.550402
118000,41.453988,-81.554598
272000,41.478278,-81.71321
193000,41.389737,-81.806958
237000,41.469768,-81.839801
458000,41.461405,-81.501236
167000,41.495068,-81.550947
98000,41.461061,-81.705367
87000,41.528795,-81.620411
140000,41.416514,-81.522673
280000,35.113076,-89.939775
129000,41.462182,-81.770669
294000,41.468942,-81.818158
187000,41.496551,-81.65133
156000,41.496551,-81.65133
80000,41.538235,-81.620539
234000,41.340449,-81.724167
154000,41.539205,-81.504106
68000,41.458083,-81.60988
67000,41.598958,-81.528403
98000,41.456772,-81.586504
152000,35.197116,-89.81058
134000,41.441131,-81.72843
84000,41.520814,-81.629809
264000,41.51196,-81.578458
132000,41.457867,-81.772089
318000,41.601059,-81.544561
224000,41.305686,-81.724923
```

Comment: The elements as visualization challenges are the data to be employed and the defects in the visualization tools. Your question does not have that data. Can you provide data that can be published?

Comment: @r-beginners Sure I can. Please see edits on the original question.

Comment: Thank you for providing the data. I am running the code based on the data you provided, but arvnormalized is defined twice with different contents, is this correct? The values in the tooltip and the drawn heatmap are different. This is not the cause of the problem. My guess is , `HeatMap(... ,radius=10,...)` the specific point is not focused.

Comment: I tried to run your code in Colab. The point of your investigation is to draw a scatter plot to see if a particular area is actually concentrated and
I tried to find out how much of the concentration was in the upper right area. It is indeed concentrated, but it doesn't look like it is having an impact. if the radius value of Heatmap() is increased, the heatmap will change, but if the zoom value is changed, the heatmap will not change. I can't extrapolate from a definite reason, but I think that setting the zoom value beyond the maximum value may have an effect.

Comment: Thank you. The ARV normalized values are not supposed to be different for the markers and heatmap - I have updated my code. I was hoping that the weighted value would have more of an impact than the concentration of points in any specific area, but that doesn't seem to be the case.